# R programming table creation

Tags: r, csv

Hey guys i am really new  to r and i am having difficulty in implementing the code i am attaching the csv file , in that csv file i need to create a table showing the average salary of males and females [CSV file for the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3oXSJHLqZqXVlJUb0RCQ1Itc3M/view) 
can you guys please me  with these questions :

Q1 .
Use R to create a table showing the average salary of males and females, who were placed. Review whether there is a gender gap in the data. In other words, observe whether the average salaries of males is higher than the average salaries of females in this dataset. and also i need to run 
 a t-test to test the following hypothesis:
H1: The average salary of the male MBAs is higher than the average salary of female MBAs.

Comment: Show us what you tried. We are not here to do your work for you. And please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

Please see GhostCat's comment link about asking a question. That being said, the following may help you figure out how to do what you ask.

There are a few handy functions that you may want to familiarize yourself with. To read csv files you will need to run `read.csv` where you can press the tab key to inform you of arguments you can enter- for example, `header = TRUE` which says the first row of the csv is only header information.

```
dat <- read.csv(file = "~\WHERE\FILENAME.csv", header = TRUE)
```

To save save any object as a data.frame you can use `as.data.frame` or `data.frame` functions.

```
df <- as.data.frame(dat)
```

To split a data.frame by some value into separate lists you can use the `split` function.

```
df_Gender <- split(df, df$Gender)
```

The best way to work on lists is to familiarize yourself with the `apply` family of functions (see a full and runnable explanation [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)).

If you run into very specific trouble while working on a step please search furiously before posting a question. Best of luck.

Comment: I am new to this , so sorry for annoying by posting the whole question . My bad

Comment: I have made a data frame for a table and now i want to find the average in this table of a certain column .  **> dean.df <- table(mba.df$Gender , mba.df$Placement )
> View(dean.df)**

Comment: so i added  mean function  'dean.df <- table(mba.df$Gender , mba.df$Placement , mean)
Error in table(mba.df$Gender, mba.df$Placement, mean) : 
  all arguments must have the same length'

Comment: I highly recommend looking up some introductory R materials if you are just looking to find the mean of column... mean(mba.df$Gender) would give you the mean of that vector.

Comment: Or mean(dean.df[, x]) where x is the column you want to subset